# Viewport Posing Problems

Tags: mesh, rigging, 3d-view, pose-mode

I'm having issues moving my rig in my viewport. For some reason when I move a bone, the mesh doesn't follow. But when I let go of the bone to finalize it's transform, then the mesh shifts to the correct position. The problem is that I can't see the model move as I'm moving the mesh.

Here is the file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/e0xvcuf681ox8nd/Cartoon_Character_After_SubSurf.blend/file

Answer (score 0):

Your nice character is what is called "Not Production-ready", its simple shape is composed by 300K vertices, while a correct Retopology could mantain the same quality with less than 5K.

In my computer everything works quite fine (i7 4 Ghz, 8 core, 32 Mb Ram, Gtx 970), but a slower machine will suffer your kind of problems.

If you want to stuck with the character as it is, you can create a low poly version to program the animation, then use the original for render.

I suggest you also to go further with rigging, as it lacks all automatic functions (IK and face features) that can make the animation process quite complicated.

Comment: So because of its poly count it’s delaying its movement in the viewport? Is that what your saying? It sounds like I could just un_subdivide it to fix this.

Comment: Never mind, i found out what the problem is. I had “Delay Refresh” on. This explains so much. Alright thank you.